# how to get the date and time in from PC2 to PC1?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, date, asp.net-mvc-3, clock-synchronization

Hello I'm having trouble how can I overcome this problem I search some articles but some examples provided is in `PHP`. As my title above how can I get the `Date and Time` from the `PC2(Server side where I publish my project)` `(example of date and time is 8/12/2016 4:40 PM)` -- and the current time of my `PC1(client side who use the project)` `(example of date and time is 8/10/2016 5:00)`. What I want is, I want to display the `server side time` into one of my label in a view. And even I manipulate / change the `PC1` date and time setting the label don't affect / change because it came from the `PC2` time. I tried to use `Datetime.now()` and try to change the setting time from the `PC1` and my label date also change after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are working with Asp.net-Mvc, you want to display your server time to client browser. If you are using Razor template engineer, Try this please:

```
<div>@Html.Label(DateTime.Now.ToString())</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<label for="">@DateTime.Now.ToString()</label>
```

Comment: The time of my server will display into the client time?.

Comment: In fact, every time you refresh your browser, your browser will send a request to the server, and the server will generate a or find the matched html document, then send the document to the client(your browser). The browser will display the document to you after it received the document.
Back to your question, `<label for="">@DateTime.Now.ToString()</label>` will generate a html label tag like this:`'<label for="">xx/xx/xxxx</label>`, every time you refresh or request the url, you will get a new generated document with the server `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @ty i just add a format because i only need the date to appear

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String strDate="";
strDate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"); // 08/12/2016 02:22 PM
```

Comment: Sorry I'm totally new in asp.net and jScript. This kind of problem given to me by my group. Where should i use your code?